# Input values of checkboxes within popup not transfered via POST

Tags: html, post, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile to show a select button ("Sonstiges" within screenshot) , which will open a popup containing a list of checkboxes for this type of attribute.

[image]

Checked items need to be shown as a count value upon closing the popup and the values itself transfered via POST upon clicking save.

The checkboxes can be selected and if I close the box and reopen they are still checked.

[image]

What is missing is the amount of checked items displayed next to the label and more importantly the values need to be trasfered via POST which is not the case.

My code:

```
<a href="#popupNested_'.$group['group_id'].'" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a" data-transition="pop" data-mini="true" style="width:32%">'.$group['group_name'].'</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupNested_'.$group['group_id'].'" data-theme="none">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" >
        <legend >'.$group['group_name'].':</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" name="attributes[]" id="attributes-' . $details[$group['group_id']]['id'][$i] .'" value="' . $details[$group['group_id']]['id'][$i] .'" ' . $isselected . '  data-mini="true">
            <label for="attributes-' . $details[$group['group_id']]['id'][$i] .'">' . $details[$group['group_id']]['name'][$i] . '</label>
        </legend>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

From my understanding, their should be a POST value called `attributes`, but there is none.

Comment: Do You build the `post` data by yourself? Maybe You need to put the checkboxes inside the `form`?

Comment: The checkboxes are within a form, however after rendering with jquery mobile they seem not to be inside the form. This is quite strange.